# Recursive Grep Command Special Characters

Tags: unix, grep

I am new to Unix and I am having trouble understanding the grep command, specifically special characters tacked on to the end of the command.  I did a bunch of research but I cannot find the right terminology to search on.  My question is as follows:

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
grep -r "Something" .

grep -r "Something" *
```

Is there a name for the special characters at the end of the command?  (ie * and .)

Are they part of a Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.
```

means *current directory*

and

```
*
```

mean *all files* in the current directory

It have nothing to do with *regex* but with `glob`s.

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs

Comment: So will . actually be recursive?  Since I am only specifying the current directory?  And when you say all files does this mean directories also?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the *location* to search; they aren't part of the regex.

In Unix, `.` means the current directory, while `*` means all files in the current directory.